# laravel excel export all records fails

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

i want to export all records from view into excel sheet using maatweb package

in my controller i used the following function

```
public function exportAll()
    {
Excel::create('POs', function ($excel)

        {
            $excel->setTitle('Pos');
            $excel->sheet('POs', function ($sheet)

            {

                $pos = PO::all();
                $arr =array();

                                foreach($pos as $po)
                                {
                                    foreach ($po->mr as $m)
                                        foreach ($po->suppliers as $supplier)

                                        {
                                            $data = array($m->mr_no, $po->po_no, $po->po_subject,
                                                $po->po_issued, $po->po_total_cost, $po->po_currency,
                                                $po->po_purchase_method, $po->po_payment_method,
                                                $po->po_delivery_method, $po->po_confirmation,
                                                $po->po_loaded_on_ideas, $supplier->vname,
                                                $po->po_loaded_on_ideas, $po->po_approved_on_ideas,
                                                $po->memo_to_fin, $po->po_delivery_date,
                                                $po->po_mr_received_date, $po->po_mrr_received_date,
                                                $po->po_invoice_received_date, $po->po_penalty,
                                                $po->po_cover_invoice, $po->po_completed

                                            );
                                            array_push($arr, $data);


                                        }
                                }

                                    $sheet->loadView( 'pos.pos_all_template' )->with('pos',$pos);
              //

                                           });
                    })->export('xlsx');
    }
```

and in route file i used
Route::get('po_s/exportall','POsController@exportAll');

in my view file

```
@foreach($pos as $p)
@foreach($p->mr as $m)
@foreach($p->suppliers as $s)

<tr style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);" align="center" >

    <th align="center" > {{ $m['mr_no'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" > {{ $p['po_no'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" > {{ $p['po_subject'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_issued'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $s['vname'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_total_cost'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_currency'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_purchase_method'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_payment_method'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_delivery_method'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_delivery_date'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_loaded_on_ideas'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_mr_received_date'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_mrr_received_date'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_invoice_received_date'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_penalty'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_cover_invoice'] }} </th>
    <th align="center" >{{ $p['po_completed'] }} </th>



</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

the problem i the receive empty excel file  without any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try this - > `dd( $pos = PO::all(););` or `enter code here`dd($pos); 
if you get output then try your **for-each** loop what you are getting when you use `dd();`. if you get data then **Creating** Excel sheet is the problem  check below code how im creating sheet

```
    public function createDocs()
        {
   \Excel::create('JOBS', function($excel) {
     $excel->sheet('2015', function($sheet) {
       $jobs = DB::table('jobs')->get();
       $data = array('JOB ID','CONSIGNEE CODE','CONSIGNEE NAME','CONSIGNEE VAT NO','DESCRIPTION','VESSEL & VOYAGE','INVOICE VALUE','ETA/ATA DATE','B/L or AWB NUMBER','COMPLETE DATE','DELIVERY INVOICE VALUE','DUTY AMOUNT','TERMINAL','PAYMENT','INCOTERMS','COM INVOICE NO','COM INVOICE DATE','COM INVOICE VALUE','BANK','BANKREFNO','ORIGIN','EXPORT','TRADING','TOTAL EXPENSES','PROFIT');
    $sheet->fromArray(array($data),null,'A1',false,false);

foreach($jobs as $row){
     $sum = DB::table('charges')->where('job_id', $row->id)->sum('amount');
     $consignee = DB::table('consignees')->where('id', $row->id)->first();
                        $data=array($row->id,$consignee->code,$consignee->name,$consignee->vat_num,$row->description,$row->vessel,
                            $row->invoice_value,$row->eta_date,$row->awb_num,$row->complete_date,$row->del_inv_val,$row->duty_amount,
                            $row->terminal,$row->payment,$row->incoterm,$row->com_inv_no,$row->com_inv_date,$row->com_inv_value,$row->bank,$row->bank_ref_no,
                            $row->country_origin,$row->country_export,$row->country_trading,$sum,$row->invoice_value-$sum);
                        $sheet->fromArray(array($data),null,'A1',false,false);
}});})->download('csv');}
```

and use this link http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export

Comment: it actually works with your code , but i need to load file from view

Comment: @Hussein view means ?? your data in your database right so you have to talk with your database?? not view?? you solved or ??